# go get accept selfsigned certificate from distant host

Tags: ssl, go

I'd like to be able to `go get` from my Stash server with a nice URL. My stash server works only over HTTPS. The problem is that my SSL certificate I'm using with stash is self-signed and any `go get` to my server gets me the following error:

```
x509: certificate signed by unknown authority
```

Is there a way to authorize self-signed certificates from `go get`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `go get -insecure https://xxxxx`.

From `go get -h`:

> The -insecure flag permits fetching from repositories and resolving
>   custom domains using insecure schemes such as HTTP. Use with caution.

Comment: Noting, that of course, there isn't a way to know if it's your own self-signed certificate you're allowing or an attacker's, which makes it somewhat pointless!

Comment: Thank you so much! I must have skip this flag when I read the help... @elithrar I know, but getting a signed certificate by a CA when you're a student is pretty hard to get haha. Thanks for the analysis I didn't really think of it this way.

Comment: @Ganitzsh It's definitely not hard to get a proper (domain verified) certificate, even as a student. You don't need to provide any formal ID. Places like Namecheap or Gandi are extremely cheap.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, it's the first I face real problems with SSL and certificates.. Pretty hard to understand at first.

Comment: Seems to be deprecated in favor of GOINSECURE (which doesn't even work in my case but oh well)

Answer (score 11):

**`go get -insecure` has been deprecated.**

As of go 1.14, the correct way to do this is by setting the [**`GOINSECURE` environment variable**](https://go.dev/doc/go1.14#go-env-vars) to a comma-separated list of domains from which you'd like to ignore the certs.

E.g. Setting in within `~/.zshrc` (if zsh shell)

```bash
GOINSECURE=example.com
```

Then you will be able to install the packages like:

```bash
go get example.com/some/pkg
```

Comment: That should be the accepted answer because the solution in the previously accepted answer is deprecated.